# Boostrap: Add image in DIV via CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project that is very extensive in terms of HTML pages, but the elements are the same. I wanted to get all the images to be called from the CSS files, just in case there is an image change, I only have to go back and change it in the css and not in 100+ HTML pages.

My problem is having the images display. Section 2 image is to be the full height of the section it is nested in, but that is not happening either.

Here the code: https://jsfiddle.net/dreacaroli/206qn38m/5/

```
<!-- Section 1 with div-->
<div class="lightyellow section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-6 column img-responsive pull-right">
                <div class="in-sch-section1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 column">
                <h2>Reduce Scheduling Phone Calls</h2>
                <p>With , your employees can check their schedules, request time off and swap shifts withouto call you.</p>
                <a href="features.aspx#section3" class="btn"> Learn More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Section 2 -->
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h2>Focustomers Insf Schedules</h2>
                <p>Create an to repeat daily, weekly or monthly, or let our auto-schedule tool do the work for you. The auto-scheduler creates random schedules based uponets.</p>
                <a href="features.aspx#section2" class="btn">Learn More</a>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="in-sch-section2"></div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /.row-->    
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the idea how section 2 is to look like:
http://s12.postimg.org/yqcxgy69p/Screen_Shot_2015_06_10_at_1_48_58_PM.png

Comment: in your fiddle, can you use absolute urls instead of relative ones? The images won't show otherwise.

Comment: On the second picture the file name has a / at the end of the .jpg

Comment: @MatthewHammond, that would inavalidate just that picture, not the others.

Comment: @yak613 sorry I didn't realise that all of the images hasn't showing

Answer (score 2):

I only had to read this far:

> I only have to go back and change it in the css and not in 100+ HTML
>   pages.

To know you're using the wrong solution, static html sites should be at most 10-20 pages and even that's pushing it. The minute you go over that there's no point in doing things that way anymore.

You need a CMS.

Furthermore:

> I wanted to get all the images to be called from the CSS files, just
>   in case there is an image change

This makes no sense, if there is an image change you'll still have to go through all 100+ of your html files and change the css filename to ensure the browser updates the cache.

You need a server language at the very least (even if you're not using a database) to do the job properly.

Comment: 1) I would love to use a CMS, but that's not possible right now (I'm not the one that can make that decision). 2) I'm trying to figure out a way that will make this awful task a bit easier. I figured if I just replaced the image and have the same css classes, I don't have to go back into the html.

Comment: Can you point me at the slimey git that can so i can earbash them for being stupid?  >_<

Comment: I cry tears of blood every day for being forced to do things the most inefficient way possible.

Comment: OK so CMS is out, can you tell me something, how many images, ballpark and what is the filesize of each one?

Comment: Why would she have to change the stylesheet filename? Just use the same stylesheet on every page. The browser cache issue is negligible, you don't rename your stylesheets every time your update them do you?

Comment: Browser does a site request, assuming the users been there before, the stylesheets and images are cached. If no file names are changed, browser takes images / css from cache and uses them instead of reflecting the change.

Comment: For the record there are other ways by fiddling with cache expiry times but they don't always work.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS to do this is certainly not the best way to do this but it can be done.

Your issue here is that you need to set the width and height of the div you're using the display the image since an empty div is 0px tall and 0px wide.

```
.example {
  background-image: url(path/to/image);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

EDIT: I should add that using the wrapper class `img-responsive` won't do anything since `.img-responsive` manipulate the `<img>` element, not the background of a `<div>`

Comment: What would be the recommended method? Adding in the img tag?

Comment: @AndreaCarolinaAvellan I'd do it server side. You could do it with javascript with something like this: HTML `<img class="example"/>` and then JS: `var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.example'); imgs.forEach(function (img) { img.src = 'path/to/src' }) `